# Do we have a notation for a quantity that is smaller or larger than x by an infinitesimal amount?

Tags: real-analysis

As far I am aware we don't have such a notation, but i think it would be useful. We could use a "+" or "-" superscript on a number (x) to represent a quantity less than or greater than (x) by an infinitesimal amount. That way we would have a nice way to indicate the real solution to ArcCot(x) = -Pi/2. The solution is a number less than 0 by an infinitesimal amount. If we don't have such a notation, do you agree that it would be useful?

Comment: That notation is already in use in the literature.  Although it is usually a trailing $+$ or $-$ rather than a superscript or subscript.  So $f(x+) := \lim_{y \searrow x} f(y)$.

Comment: What's wrong with limits?

Comment: You can just say $S=-\varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon\gt 0\,$  [infinitesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)

Comment: IMHO that's commonly called an _error_, i.e. $\Delta x$ in $x \pm \Delta x$

Comment: @E.O. What's wrong with limits? Complicated things will be more readable if we have concise notation. We may have never found solutions to PDEs if the were expressed in terms of: For every epsilonX, epsilonY, there exists a deltaX, deltaY such that ....

Comment: @Han de Bruijn, Error is a totally different topic. Using the notation mentioned above by Stephen Montgomery-Smith "2+" is a quantity that is larger than 2 by an infinitely small amount. Also "2-" is smaller than 2 by an infinitely small amount. A useful application is  ArcTan(0-) = -Pi/2.

Comment: What do you mean by: a "quantity" less than or greater than $x$ by an "infinitesimal" amount?  What do you mean by "infinitesimal"?  There is no real number that is less than $0$ by an infinitesimal amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation is already in use in the literature. Although it is usually a trailing $+$ or $−$ rather than a superscript or subscript. So $f(x+):=\lim_{y\searrow x}f(y)$.